# Customer Grid - Add custom action

Tags: magento-1.8, csv, customer-grid

I want to add a custom csv export to the customer grid page. Whats the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 6):

1. extend the select
2. implement own controller
3. do it

I even have an alternative. The CSV export is based on the shown columns, so you can change the columns, e.h. while using [GridControle](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl) to have your export, then you get what you want.